# Chrome banning Third party cookies and Cross Domain Authentication

Tags: reactjs, cross-domain, third-party-cookies

I recently came across that third party cookies will be banned in most browsers from 2022. (Most notably, chrome)
My current setup involves a React front-end server (on domain A) and an express-passport backend server using cookies (transferred using axios useCredententials: true on domain B) as authentication.
Is this setup not recommended? If so, what other configurations should I implement as best practices?

Thanks in advance.